# Pointfree returning a tuple in Haskell

Tags: haskell, pointfree

Can a pointfree function return a tuple? For instance, can the following be written in pointfree style (where f1, f2, and f3 have been defined):

```
(\t -> (f1 t, f2 t, f3 t))
```

In this case, my f1, f2, and f3 are compositions of quot, mod, *, and some integers.

```
(\f1,f2,f3 -> (\t -> (f1 t, f2 t, f3 t)))
```

is a more general case, and is equivalent to

```
(\f1,f2,f3,t -> (f1 t, f2 t, f3 t))
```

Named functions are OK, but my examples are anonymous. (Named examples would be as follows)

```
f x = (f1 x, f2 x, f3 x)
f f1 f2 f3 x = (f1 x, f2 x, f3 x)
```

EDIT: I'm just curious for fun, I'm not going to do this.

Comment: By the way, don't use `quot` and `mod` together. Either use `quot` and `rem` (or just `quotRem`) or use `div` and `mod` (or just use `divMod`). These pairings have guarantees, namely, that `quotRem m n = (q, r)` implies `n * q + r = m` (and similarly for `divMod`).

Comment: why have two pairs, by the way?

Comment: `quotRem` and `divMod` have different behaviors on negative numbers. `divMod` always returns a positive `mod` part, but `quotRem` is typically a tiny bit faster.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can write

```
(\t -> (f1 t, f2 t, f3 t))
```

pointfree, it's

```
liftM (,,) f1 `ap` f2 `ap` f3
```

with `ap` from `Control.Monad` and the `Monad` instance of `(->) a` from `Control.Monad.Instances`. A somewhat more readable form may be the `Control.Applicative` variant

```
(,,) <$> f1 <*> f2 <*> f3
```

You can then further point-free

```
(\f1 f2 f3 -> (\t -> (f1 t, f2 t, f3 t)))
```

As

```
  \f1 f2 f3 -> (,,) <$> f1 <*> f2 <*> f3
= \f1 f2 -> ((,,) <$> f1 <*> f2 <*>)
= \f1 f2 -> (<*>) ((,,) <$> f1 <*> f2)
= \f1 f2 -> ((<*>) . ((,,) <$> f1 <*>)) f2
= \f1 -> (<*>) . ((,,) <$> f1 <*>)
= \f1 -> (<*>) . (<*>) ((,,) <$> f1)
= \f1 -> (((<*>) .) . (<*>) . (<$>) (,,)) f1
= ((<*>) .) . (<*>) . (<$>) (,,)
```

but seriously, you shouldn't. Keep it readable, that means a bit of pointfreeing is good, but don't overdo it.

Comment: I think this answer is much better than mine, I was mostly forwarding what lambdabot gave. In particular, I like the `Control.Applicative` variant!

Answer (score 4):

Yes. The "lambdabot" IRC bot on the #haskell IRC channel actually has a feature which gives you the point-free version of a given function. In your case, it says that

```
\x -> (f x, g x, h x)
```

is equivalent to

```
ap (liftM2 (,,) f g) h
```

Comment: I love how lambdabot uses the function monad.

Answer (score 4):

Although the applicative or monadic version is simpler and shorter, one way that perhaps exposes the "meaning" (and what property of the category of Haskell types you are using) is using Control.Arrow

```
uncurry (uncurry (,,)) . ((f &&& g) &&& h)
```

The pointfull version is superior though.

This also exposes that you need the "Cartesianess" of Hask, but not all the "Closedness" of Hask

```
 arrowized :: Arrow cat => cat a a1 -> cat a b1 -> cat a b -> cat a (a1, b1, b)
 arrowized f g h => arr (uncurry (uncurry (,,))) . ((f &&& g) &&& h)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can write your example like this:

```
\f1 f2 f3 t -> (,,) (f1 t) (f2 t) (f3 t)
```

(,,) is a usual function with 3 arguments, so there's nothing special in making its application pointfree. However, it uses its argument 3 times so it's going to be cumbersome and it's probably not worth it.

Lambdabot at #haskell says it's `(ap .) . liftM2 (,,)`. Enjoy :)

Answer (score 2):

Here's some elaboration on the other's answers here.

Inside the source code for `Control.Applicative` we find

```
instance Applicative ((->) a) where  -- (a ->) is meant here
    pure = const
    (<*>) f g x = f x (g x)

liftA3 f a b c = f <$> a <*> b <*> c
```

In GHCi, we get

```
Prelude Control.Applicative> :t liftA3 (,,)
liftA3 (,,) :: (Applicative f) => f a -> f b -> f c -> f (a, b, c)
```

So, with `(t->)` as `f`, **`liftA3 (,,)`** just works:

```
liftA3 (,,) ~ (t->a) -> (t->b) -> (t->c) -> (t->(a,b,c))
```

I.e., calling **`liftA3 (,,) f1 f2 f3 t`** produces a triple `(f1 t, f2 t, f3 t)`, given three functions on same-type input:

`Prelude Control.Applicative>` **`` liftA3 (,,) (:[]) (quot 12) (`rem`3) 4 ``**
`([4],3,1)`

---

So, how does it work? By the definiton of `liftA3`, and then of `<*>`,

```
liftA3 (,,) f g h t = ((((,,) <$> f) <*> g) <*> h) t
    = (((,,) <$> f) <*> g) t (h t)
    = (((,,) <$> f) t (g t) (h t)
```

Now, `(<$>) = fmap` and `instance Functor ((->) t)` defines `fmap = (.)`, so we continue

```
    = (((,,) . f) t (g t) (h t)
    = (,,) (f t) (g t) (h t)
    = (f t, g t, h t)
```